# PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA2 test vectors

Tags: cryptography, hmac, sha2, pbkdf2

There are test vectors for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 in [RFC6070](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6070). There are test vectors for HMAC-SHA2 in [RFC4231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4231).

But so far I haven't found test vectors for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA2 anywhere.

I'm most interested in SHA256, so I'll post some vectors I calculated with my implementation. I'd be happy if someone could verify/confirm them, or contribute their own.

Comment: You might consider writing an RFC that describes how to use PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256 in RFC 2898, and includes the test vectors also. You should do it for all the SHA2 hashes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I [implemented PBKDF2](http://althenia.net/svn/stackoverflow/pbkdf2-test-vectors.py?rev=6) using the standard [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) and [hmac](http://docs.python.org/library/hmac.html) modules in Python and checked the output against both the RFC 6070 vectors and the [vectors you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130513/pbkdf2-hmac-sha2-test-vectors/5130543#5130543) – it matches.

Here are the vectors I get with a larger `dkLen` to match the larger digest output size. This is the output of `pbkdf2-test-vectors.py sha256`, which takes about 10 minutes to run.

```
PBKDF2 HMAC-SHA256 Test Vectors

Input:
  P = "password" (8 octets)
  S = "salt" (4 octets)
  c = 1
  dkLen = 32

Output:
  DK = 12 0f b6 cf fc f8 b3 2c
       43 e7 22 52 56 c4 f8 37
       a8 65 48 c9 2c cc 35 48
       08 05 98 7c b7 0b e1 7b (32 octets)


Input:
  P = "password" (8 octets)
  S = "salt" (4 octets)
  c = 2
  dkLen = 32

Output:
  DK = ae 4d 0c 95 af 6b 46 d3
       2d 0a df f9 28 f0 6d d0
       2a 30 3f 8e f3 c2 51 df
       d6 e2 d8 5a 95 47 4c 43 (32 octets)


Input:
  P = "password" (8 octets)
  S = "salt" (4 octets)
  c = 4096
  dkLen = 32

Output:
  DK = c5 e4 78 d5 92 88 c8 41
       aa 53 0d b6 84 5c 4c 8d
       96 28 93 a0 01 ce 4e 11
       a4 96 38 73 aa 98 13 4a (32 octets)


Input:
  P = "password" (8 octets)
  S = "salt" (4 octets)
  c = 16777216
  dkLen = 32

Output:
  DK = cf 81 c6 6f e8 cf c0 4d
       1f 31 ec b6 5d ab 40 89
       f7 f1 79 e8 9b 3b 0b cb
       17 ad 10 e3 ac 6e ba 46 (32 octets)


Input:
  P = "passwordPASSWORDpassword" (24 octets)
  S = "saltSALTsaltSALTsaltSALTsaltSALTsalt" (36 octets)
  c = 4096
  dkLen = 40

Output:
  DK = 34 8c 89 db cb d3 2b 2f
       32 d8 14 b8 11 6e 84 cf
       2b 17 34 7e bc 18 00 18
       1c 4e 2a 1f b8 dd 53 e1
       c6 35 51 8c 7d ac 47 e9 (40 octets)


Input:
  P = "pass\0word" (9 octets)
  S = "sa\0lt" (5 octets)
  c = 4096
  dkLen = 16

Output:
  DK = 89 b6 9d 05 16 f8 29 89
       3c 69 62 26 65 0a 86 87 (16 octets)
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce all your results correctly in JavaScript using the [SJCL library](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl).

Comment: As well as varying the output size, it might be necessary to extend the input size in test case 5 to have the same effect as the RFC test vectors - passwordPASSWORDpassword at 24 octets exceeded the output size of the SHA1 output, but doesn't exceed the size of your SHA256 output. It's possible this misses some codepaths the RFC test vectors follow - although probably not; I suspect the password would have to exceed the 64-byte block size to make a difference in either case.

Comment: Thanks so much for posting test vectors! Can you post one with 64 or more bytes?

Comment: Almsot forgot: I was able to replicate yours with an implementation I did based on the RFC

Comment: Encoding is one source for incompatibilities. Personally I prefer using UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: Confirmed using the Java PBKDF2 functionality.

Comment: **Warning**: the "default" character encoding of PBKDF2 is UTF-8. You may want to test special characters as well. Java would fail that because it only complies with Windows-1252 (ASCII + 128 special characters).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Java uses "Unicode" (actually UTF-16) for Strings and chars, and supports 
hundreds of encodings to/from bytes for I/O and similar things like crypto. The *default* 
encoding varies; for Windows it is (usually?) cp1252 but other platforms are different. For crypto 
exactly reproducible data is vital so you should use an explicit encoding not the default, 
typically UTF-8 to support the broadest data, especially here where 2898 recommends (but doesn't require) UTF-8.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I know that, but the PBKDF2 implementation only uses the lower 8 bits of the `char` values in the `char[]` (because of security considerations). This maps more or less to Windows-1252, though I would strongly recommend to keep to ASCII for Java.

Comment: Confirmed using [OpenSSL::PKCS5](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS5.html) in Ruby. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/declan/e77c8e96b7f19e250604ce5b3ae275f7).

Comment: Did anyone consider putting this into an RFC, yet?

Comment: Find test vectors here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7914#section-11

Answer (score 7):

Test vectors for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA256:

Input values were taken from RFC6070; c is the number of rounds.

```
Input:
 P = "password" (8 octets)
 S = "salt" (4 octets)
 c = 1
 dkLen = 20
Output:
 DK = 12 0f b6 cf fc f8 b3 2c 43 e7 22 52 56 c4 f8 37 a8 65 48 c9


Input:
 P = "password" (8 octets)
 S = "salt" (4 octets)
 c = 2
 dkLen = 20
Output:
 DK = ae 4d 0c 95 af 6b 46 d3 2d 0a df f9 28 f0 6d d0 2a 30 3f 8e


Input:
 P = "password" (8 octets)
 S = "salt" (4 octets)
 c = 4096
 dkLen = 20
Output:
 DK = c5 e4 78 d5 92 88 c8 41 aa 53 0d b6 84 5c 4c 8d 96 28 93 a0


Input:
 P = "password" (8 octets)
 S = "salt" (4 octets)
 c = 16777216
 dkLen = 20
Output:
 DK = cf 81 c6 6f e8 cf c0 4d 1f 31 ec b6 5d ab 40 89 f7 f1 79 e8


Input:
 P = "passwordPASSWORDpassword" (24 octets)
 S = "saltSALTsaltSALTsaltSALTsaltSALTsalt" (36 octets)
 c = 4096
 dkLen = 25
Output:
 DK = 34 8c 89 db cb d3 2b 2f 32 d8 14 b8 11 6e 84 cf
      2b 17 34 7e bc 18 00 18 1c


Input:
 P = "pass\0word" (9 octets)
 S = "sa\0lt" (5 octets)
 c = 4096
 dkLen = 16
Output:
 DK = 89 b6 9d 05 16 f8 29 89 3c 69 62 26 65 0a 86 87
```

Comment: I think `dkLen = 20` reflects the digest size, so for SHA-256 you should use 32. `dkLen = 25` should be larger than the digest size, so that it covers the code path dealing with multiple `T` blocks; maybe 40.

Comment: @aaz: No.  `dkLen` is the [*Derived Key Length*](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898#section-2).  The digest size is specified in the algorithm by `hlen` which isn't an input to the PBKDF2 function directly...

Comment: @ircmaxell – Yes. I meant that the `dkLen` for the testcases was chosen to match the `hLen` of the PRF being used. So when adapting the testcases for a different PRF the `dkLen` should be adjusted.

Comment: dkLen < 32 is a valid test, but dkLen >= 32 would help a lot since if it's under 32, it'll just crop off the extra octets

Comment: There should be at least a test > 32. On the other hand, I've got no problem replicating the above test values.

Comment: Good for testing a key length that is greater then hLen.
```
Input:
    P = "password" (8 octets)
    S = "salt" (4 octets)
    c = 4096
    dkLen = 100
Output:
    DK = c5 e4 78 d5 92 88 c8 41 aa 53 0d b6 84 5c 4c 8d
         96 28 93 a0 01 ce 4e 11 a4 96 38 73 aa 98 13 4a
         f7 ad 98 c1 b4 58 ce 3f d7 4c a3 5b eb a3 cd a7
         b8 d1 03 8d 6a 87 07 1b 91 8f 83 74 05 f3 fe 77
         28 ff e7 f0 97 6f c3 5d d8 2f c0 e5 e4 6c e9 ce
         26 a7 88 b2 c7 d1 83 fa 5b f8 d9 60 7e ec d7 1d
         01 b4 f1 19
```

Answer (score 5):

I should probably finally post what I did awhile ago based on this very question!

At [my Github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-Test-Vectors/releases), I have compiled test vectors for

- PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512
- PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-384
- PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-256
- PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-224
- PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1
  And for the crazy or those with ancient systems without even SHA-1 support:
- PBKDF2-HMAC-MD5

Tests started with RFC6070 and those in the answer by @ChristianAichinger above for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-256, and added a few dozen more to implement more stringent tests, such as boundary conditions around certain sizes of password and salt (15/16/17 bytes, 63/64/65 bytes, 127/128/129 bytes, 1025 bytes etc.), large iteration counts, large output size counts, and so on and so forth.

I then gathered up many instances of PBKDF2, and validated these test vectors against every major implementation I was able to find (all also included in the above repository, sometimes including Windows MinGW executables and generally including Linux compilation instructions), including

- Python (hashlib)
- Python (warner's custom code)
- C (OpenSSL)
- C (PolarSSL)
- C++ (Cryptopp)
- .NET 4.5 (@Jither's DeriveBytes)
- SQL Server (custom code, PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-1 and PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 only right now)

Given that I'm seeing identical results across 7 implementations using 5 different languages using multiple major cryptographic libraries, I'm extremely confident that not only are the test vectors provided accurate, but that the implementations provided can be used as a set to validate any other test vector set desired.  If they all agree, then it's correct.

Comment: I think people would find your test vectors a lot more useful if you distributed them in a more easily accessible format than an ODS spreadsheet – I think JSON format would be the ideal.

Comment: The test vectors can be found in pbkdf2_test.sh at https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-GCC-OpenSSL-library       or any of the related PBKDF2 implementation repositories.
The ODS spreadsheet is explicitly to _generate_ test vectors; feel free to write up =CONCATENATE statements for JSON or any other output you like.

Answer (score 2):

As part of [RFC-7914](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7914.txt) (*scrypt* specifications) there are test vectors provided for *PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA-256* (since *scrypt* uses *PBKDF2* internally).

Here they are:

```
   PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-256 (P="passwd", S="salt",
                       c=1, dkLen=64) =
   55 ac 04 6e 56 e3 08 9f ec 16 91 c2 25 44 b6 05
   f9 41 85 21 6d de 04 65 e6 8b 9d 57 c2 0d ac bc
   49 ca 9c cc f1 79 b6 45 99 16 64 b3 9d 77 ef 31
   7c 71 b8 45 b1 e3 0b d5 09 11 20 41 d3 a1 97 83

   PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-256 (P="Password", S="NaCl",
                        c=80000, dkLen=64) =
   4d dc d8 f6 0b 98 be 21 83 0c ee 5e f2 27 01 f9
   64 1a 44 18 d0 4c 04 14 ae ff 08 87 6b 34 ab 56
   a1 d4 25 a1 22 58 33 54 9a db 84 1b 51 c9 b3 17
   6a 27 2b de bb a1 d0 78 47 8f 62 b3 97 f3 3c 8d
```

Interestingly, `dkLen` goes over `32` (the size of a SHA-256 block), so it does test that the concatenation of the intermediate hash blocks works.