# Java - PBKDF2 with HMACSHA256 as the PRF

Tags: authentication, hash, cryptography, md5, pbkdf2

I've been given the task of creating a Login API for our project and I'm supposed to use PBKDF2 with HMACSHA256 as the PRF.  The plain text password is hashed using MD5 and then fed into the PBKDF2 to generate a derived key.  The problem is, I'm not able to get the same output as what the project documentation is telling me.

Here's the PBKDF2 Implementation in Java:

```java
public class PBKDF2
{
    public static byte[] deriveKey( byte[] password, byte[] salt, int iterationCount, int dkLen )
        throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException, java.security.InvalidKeyException
    {
        SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec( password, "HmacSHA256" );
        Mac prf = Mac.getInstance( "HmacSHA256" );
        prf.init( keyspec );

        // Note: hLen, dkLen, l, r, T, F, etc. are horrible names for
        //       variables and functions in this day and age, but they
        //       reflect the terse symbols used in RFC 2898 to describe
        //       the PBKDF2 algorithm, which improves validation of the
        //       code vs. the RFC.
        //
        // dklen is expressed in bytes. (16 for a 128-bit key)

        int hLen = prf.getMacLength();   // 20 for SHA1
        int l = Math.max( dkLen, hLen); //  1 for 128bit (16-byte) keys
        int r = dkLen - (l-1)*hLen;      // 16 for 128bit (16-byte) keys
        byte T[] = new byte[l * hLen];
        int ti_offset = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= l; i++) {
            F( T, ti_offset, prf, salt, iterationCount, i );
            ti_offset += hLen;
        }

        if (r < hLen) {
            // Incomplete last block
            byte DK[] = new byte[dkLen];
            System.arraycopy(T, 0, DK, 0, dkLen);
            return DK;
        }
        return T;
    } 


    private static void F( byte[] dest, int offset, Mac prf, byte[] S, int c, int blockIndex ) {
        final int hLen = prf.getMacLength();
        byte U_r[] = new byte[ hLen ];
        // U0 = S || INT (i);
        byte U_i[] = new byte[S.length + 4];
        System.arraycopy( S, 0, U_i, 0, S.length );
        INT( U_i, S.length, blockIndex );
        for( int i = 0; i < c; i++ ) {
            U_i = prf.doFinal( U_i );
            xor( U_r, U_i );
        }

        System.arraycopy( U_r, 0, dest, offset, hLen );
    }

    private static void xor( byte[] dest, byte[] src ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < dest.length; i++ ) {
            dest[i] ^= src[i];
        }
    }

    private static void INT( byte[] dest, int offset, int i ) {
        dest[offset + 0] = (byte) (i / (256 * 256 * 256));
        dest[offset + 1] = (byte) (i / (256 * 256));
        dest[offset + 2] = (byte) (i / (256));
        dest[offset + 3] = (byte) (i);
    } 

    // ctor
    private PBKDF2 () {}

}
```

I used test vectors found here [PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA2 test vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130513/pbkdf2-hmac-sha2-test-vectors/5136918#5136918) to verify the correctness of the implementation and it all checked out.  I'm not sure why I couldn't the same results with an MD5 hashed password.

Parameters:

```
Salt: 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F
Iterations Count: 1000
DKLen: 16 (128-bit derived key)
```

Using "foobar" as the plaintext password, the expected results are:

```
PWHash = MD5(PlaintextPassword) = 3858f62230ac3c915f300c664312c63f
PWKey = PBKDF2(PWHash, Salt, IterationsCount, DKLen) = 33C37758EFA6780C5E52FAB3B50F329C
```

What I get:

```
PWHash = 3858f62230ac3c915f300c664312c63f
PWKey = 0bd0c7d8339df2c66ce4b6e1e91ed3f1
```

Comment: Why are you certain the "expected" results are correct?

Comment: I don't know if they are, but the rest of the authentication process + client-server communication in the project documentation uses this expected result in its examples to create crypto messages with AES-ECB to communicate with the server so I'd assume its correct.

Comment: Your method takes a byte array as the password parameter.  How are you converting the text "foobar" into bytes?

Comment: To be honest, I'm being lazy because I don't want to read your code :)

Comment: @rossum MD5("foobar") = 3858f62230ac3c915f300c664312c63f, which are the bytes I feed into PBKDF2.
- GregS: I'm not expecting you or anyone to :)  But you can just cut and paste this solution, which I got from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012363/java-equivalent-of-cs-rfc2898derivedbytes into a Java IDE and run it in less than 5 minutes

Comment: Since you've already run test vectors through your code it is unlikely that is the problem. It is the other code I'm worried about, the one yours is expected to match. Maybe the other code treats the salt as a string of hex characters instead of a byte array, as just one example.

Comment: Hmm, that could be a possibility.  I used java String.getBytes() call on the salt and also ran it through a hexStringToByteArray() method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java and couldn't produce the same results.  Our documentation states that the salt is "ASCII hex text of up to 256."  In this case, the salt is exactly 256 bits (if put into a byte array, each element is a number from 0-31).  Not sure what else it could be :(

Comment: This is wrong: `int l = Math.max( dkLen, hLen);`, but since that would give other problems, I guess that you have made some changes to your code before submitting your question.

Comment: I get the same results as you (from a different implementation). Chances are that either your project documentation is wrong, you have read it wrong or that you are using the wrong input parameters.

Comment: For the Math.max function, there was a CEIL function that was implemented according the the RFC spec.  The author of the modified code I posted just simplified it by replacing it with Math.max.  I think that part only influences the length of the DK.

Comment: Haha I figured it out on accident.  The iteration count is supposed to be 4096.  I don't know why the documentation says 1000.  Looks like the author made a mistake.  Thank you for all the help peeps.

Comment: You may notice that 4096 = 0x1000

Comment: Interesting I didn't realize that.  Regardless, my documentation never said anything about changing the iterations count from hex->integer.  Plus, the RFC spec says the iterations count is supposed to be an integer.  Thank you anyways.

Comment: @AndroidNoob: `0x1000` is just as much an integer as `4096` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iterations count was supposed to 4096, not 1000.

Answer (score 0):

The generation of `int l` seems wrong. You have specified the maximum between `dkLen` and `hLen` but the spec says `l = CEIL (dkLen / hLen)` with

> CEIL (x) is the "ceiling" function, i.e. the smallest integer greater than, or equal to, x.

I think `l` would be more accurately defined as `l = (int)Math.ceil( (double)dkLen / (double)hLen )`