# PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 test vectors

Tags: cryptography, pbkdf2

I have not been able to find published test vectors for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512.  I've built a function that (finally!) reproduces the 7 HMAC-SHA-512 test vectors in [RFC 4231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4231), and the 32-byte test vectors for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-256 found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130513/pbkdf2-hmac-sha2-test-vectors).

Here is what it generates for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512.  Can anyone help me verify this output?
Thanks,
Fred

```
Input:
  P = "password"
  S = "salt"
  c = 1
  dkLen = 64

Output:
  DK = 86 7f 70 cf 1a de 02 cf 
       f3 75 25 99 a3 a5 3d c4 
       af 34 c7 a6 69 81 5a e5 
       d5 13 55 4e 1c 8c f2 52 
       c0 2d 47 0a 28 5a 05 01 
       ba d9 99 bf e9 43 c0 8f 
       05 02 35 d7 d6 8b 1d a5 
       5e 63 f7 3b 60 a5 7f ce 

 
Input:
  P = "password"
  S = "salt"
  c = 2
  dkLen = 64

Output:
  DK = e1 d9 c1 6a a6 81 70 8a 
       45 f5 c7 c4 e2 15 ce b6 
       6e 01 1a 2e 9f 00 40 71 
       3f 18 ae fd b8 66 d5 3c 
       f7 6c ab 28 68 a3 9b 9f 
       78 40 ed ce 4f ef 5a 82 
       be 67 33 5c 77 a6 06 8e 
       04 11 27 54 f2 7c cf 4e 


Input:
  P = "password"
  S = "salt"
  c = 4096
  dkLen = 64

Output:
  DK = d1 97 b1 b3 3d b0 14 3e 
       01 8b 12 f3 d1 d1 47 9e 
       6c de bd cc 97 c5 c0 f8 
       7f 69 02 e0 72 f4 57 b5 
       14 3f 30 60 26 41 b3 d5 
       5c d3 35 98 8c b3 6b 84 
       37 60 60 ec d5 32 e0 39 
       b7 42 a2 39 43 4a f2 d5 


Input:
  P = "passwordPASSWORDpassword"
  S = "saltSALTsaltSALTsaltSALTsaltSALTsalt"
  c = 4096
  dkLen = 64

Output:
  DK = 8c 05 11 f4 c6 e5 97 c6 
       ac 63 15 d8 f0 36 2e 22 
       5f 3c 50 14 95 ba 23 b8 
       68 c0 05 17 4d c4 ee 71 
       11 5b 59 f9 e6 0c d9 53 
       2f a3 3e 0f 75 ae fe 30 
       22 5c 58 3a 18 6c d8 2b 
       d4 da ea 97 24 a3 d3 b8
```

Comment: Can't you just confirm with a standard implementation from, e.g., Java? That would be as accurate as asking people on SO. I've voted to close as "too localized" because I can't see this question having any use to others in the future.

Comment: Isn't it useful to have test vectors published for all of these functions?  They are already available for the low-byte-count hashes, and more applications are moving to the stronger hashes.

Comment: Is this your own implementation, Fred? If so I can see what I can do using bouncy castle. ASCII encoding for password and salt?

Comment: Thanks! yes - It's a script I wrote to calculate the HMAC and PBKDF2 using Ward's implementation of SHA2-512.  The encoding is UTF-8, which should be the same as ASCII for normal characters.  Please let me know if you know of other vectors I can test against.

Comment: I agree it is reasonable to have test vectors - particularly if this is recommended somewhere such as NIST.  Short of that, have you considered testing the hash with the SHA2 test vectors and the PBKDF2 with the PBKDF-SHA1 test vectors separately?  It would be a promising start and good tests to keep around.

Comment: @Thomas, Good idea - I will implement SHA1, and see if it reproduces the PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 test vectors in RFC6070

Comment: @owlstead (repost of comment to trigger notification) Thanks! yes - It's a script I wrote to calculate the HMAC and PBKDF2 using Ward's implementation of SHA2-512. The encoding is UTF-8, which should be the same as ASCII for normal characters. Please let me know if you know of other vectors I can test against.

Comment: @Thomas, it duplicates the 20-byte PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 test vectors in RFC6070 (except for the (untried) 16mm iteration test).  Let me know if you see any other test vectors that should be tried

Comment: Hmm, have to check against latest source of Bouncy, seems like it is not in there. No worries, I've implemented a lot of KDF's already, if it is not in there, it will be...

Comment: Sorry, bit sidetracked by moving to another place, try to get something going asap.

Comment: (Deleted and recreated comment) I forgot to update the HMAC in my old implementation from SHA256 to SHA512, so the old comment where I got different results is void.

Comment: @Fred Federspiel - Any chance of sharing the code for your implementation?

Comment: @Developr -I will try to find time to clean up the code and post it.  Please let me know if you are able to verify the PBKDF2-512 test vectors above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to verify all results against one I created

With another run to verify my own results, I verified  P = "password" S = "salt" c = 4096 dkLen = 64  with a BouncyCastle implementation that was copy/pasted from SO

Thank you so much for posting test vectors. I hope more people will verify

Answer (score 10):

I can also confirm the 4 test cases in the question generate valid results on implementations in my T-SQL, Python, with OpenSSL and PolarSSL libraries, and in a .NET library by @JimmiTh.

I'd like to add another set of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 test vectors for others to try on their own implementations - these are specifically designed to test various digest size and block size boundary conditions.

Character encoding is ASCII/UTF-8.

Tested against OpenSSL 1.0.1e on 64-bit Debian and 1.0.1f on 64-bit Windows with a 32-bit OpenSSL library called from C, [Mitsuhiko's Python PBKDF2 implementation](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-pbkdf2) with [warner's patch](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-pbkdf2/issues/2), [my own SQL Server 2012 implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19898192/1967612), PolarSSL 1.2.9 and 1.3.4, [@JimmiTh's .NET](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-CSharp-DeriveBytes-custom-A), and @TonPlomp's LabView implementation.

Note that previous differences between Python and T-SQL vs. OpenSSL were apparently due to a platform/version issue between Windows, MinGW, and OpenSSL.  There is no difference between the implementations using MinGW 4.8.1 and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.

I recommend copy/pasting these into LibreOffice Calc or Excel and using =CONCATENATE to create a test script for yourself, or get the full original LibreOffice at [Github](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-Test-Vectors/releases).

The actual test vectors, minus Ext 10b and Trunc 10a and the last two 16M iteration vectors due to SO's 30,000 character limit:

```
'Password', 'Salt', Iterations, Outputbytes, ResultInHex, 'Notes'

'passDATAb00AB7YxDTT', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD' 1 64 0xCBE6088AD4359AF42E603C2A33760EF9D4017A7B2AAD10AF46F992C660A0B461ECB0DC2A79C2570941BEA6A08D15D6887E79F32B132E1C134E9525EEDDD744FA 'AW 1a 1iter 64outBytes 19pw 19sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTT', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD' 100000 64 0xACCDCD8798AE5CD85804739015EF2A11E32591B7B7D16F76819B30B0D49D80E1ABEA6C9822B80A1FDFE421E26F5603ECA8A47A64C9A004FB5AF8229F762FF41F 'AW 1b 100000iter 64outBytes 19pw 19sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTl', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2' 1 64 0x8E5074A9513C1F1512C9B1DF1D8BFFA9D8B4EF9105DFC16681222839560FB63264BED6AABF761F180E912A66E0B53D65EC88F6A1519E14804EBA6DC9DF137007 'AW 2a 1iter 64outBytes 20pw 20sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTl', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2' 100000 64 0x594256B0BD4D6C9F21A87F7BA5772A791A10E6110694F44365CD94670E57F1AECD797EF1D1001938719044C7F018026697845EB9AD97D97DE36AB8786AAB5096 'AW 2b 100000iter 64outBytes 20pw 20sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlR', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2P' 1 64 0xA6AC8C048A7DFD7B838DA88F22C3FAB5BFF15D7CB8D83A62C6721A8FAF6903EAB6152CB7421026E36F2FFEF661EB4384DC276495C71B5CAB72E1C1A38712E56B 'AW 3a 1iter 64outBytes 21pw 21sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlR', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2P' 100000 64 0x94FFC2B1A390B7B8A9E6A44922C330DB2B193ADCF082EECD06057197F35931A9D0EC0EE5C660744B50B61F23119B847E658D179A914807F4B8AB8EB9505AF065 'AW 3b 100000iter 64outBytes 21pw 21sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE5', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJe' 1 64 0xE2CCC7827F1DD7C33041A98906A8FD7BAE1920A55FCB8F831683F14F1C3979351CB868717E5AB342D9A11ACF0B12D3283931D609B06602DA33F8377D1F1F9902 'AW 4a 1iter 64outBytes 63pw 63sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE5', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJe' 100000 64 0x07447401C85766E4AED583DE2E6BF5A675EABE4F3618281C95616F4FC1FDFE6ECBC1C3982789D4FD941D6584EF534A78BD37AE02555D9455E8F089FDB4DFB6BB 'AW 4b 100000iter 64outBytes 63pw 63sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJem' 1 64 0xB029A551117FF36977F283F579DC7065B352266EA243BDD3F920F24D4D141ED8B6E02D96E2D3BDFB76F8D77BA8F4BB548996AD85BB6F11D01A015CE518F9A717 'AW 5a 1iter 64outBytes 64pw 64sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJem' 100000 64 0x31F5CC83ED0E948C05A15735D818703AAA7BFF3F09F5169CAF5DBA6602A05A4D5CFF5553D42E82E40516D6DC157B8DAEAE61D3FEA456D964CB2F7F9A63BBBDB5 'AW 5b 100000iter 64outBytes 64pw 64sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemk' 1 64 0x28B8A9F644D6800612197BB74DF460272E2276DE8CC07AC4897AC24DBC6EB77499FCAF97415244D9A29DA83FC347D09A5DBCFD6BD63FF6E410803DCA8A900AB6 'AW 6a 1iter 64outBytes 65pw 65sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemk' 100000 64 0x056BC9072A356B7D4DA60DD66F5968C2CAA375C0220EDA6B47EF8E8D105ED68B44185FE9003FBBA49E2C84240C9E8FD3F5B2F4F6512FD936450253DB37D10028 'AW 6b 100000iter 64outBytes 65pw 65sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi0', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy' 1 64 0x16226C85E4F8D604573008BFE61C10B6947B53990450612DD4A3077F7DEE2116229E68EFD1DF6D73BD3C6D07567790EEA1E8B2AE9A1B046BE593847D9441A1B7 'AW 7a 1iter 64outBytes 127pw 127sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi0', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy' 100000 64 0x70CF39F14C4CAF3C81FA288FB46C1DB52D19F72722F7BC84F040676D3371C89C11C50F69BCFBC3ACB0AB9E92E4EF622727A916219554B2FA121BEDDA97FF3332 'AW 7b 100000iter 64outBytes 127pw 127sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6' 1 64 0x880C58C316D3A5B9F05977AB9C60C10ABEEBFAD5CE89CAE62905C1C4F80A0A098D82F95321A6220F8AECCFB45CE6107140899E8D655306AE6396553E2851376C 'AW 8a 1iter 64outBytes 128pw 128sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6' 100000 64 0x2668B71B3CA56136B5E87F30E098F6B4371CB5ED95537C7A073DAC30A2D5BE52756ADF5BB2F4320CB11C4E16B24965A9C790DEF0CBC62906920B4F2EB84D1D4A 'AW 8b 100000iter 64outBytes 128pw 128sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6P' 1 64 0x93B9BA8283CC17D50EF3B44820828A258A996DE258225D24FB59990A6D0DE82DFB3FE2AC201952100E4CC8F06D883A9131419C0F6F5A6ECB8EC821545F14ADF1 'AW 9a 1iter 64outBytes 129pw 129sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6P' 100000 64 0x2575B485AFDF37C260B8F3386D33A60ED929993C9D48AC516EC66B87E06BE54ADE7E7C8CB3417C81603B080A8EEFC56072811129737CED96236B9364E22CE3A5 'AW 9b 100000iter 64outBytes 129pw 129sa'
'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', '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' 1 64 0x384BCD6914407E40C295D1037CF4F990E8F0E720AF43CB706683177016D36D1A14B3A7CF22B5DF8D5D7D44D69610B64251ADE2E7AB54A3813A89935592E391BF 'AW 10a 1iter 64outBytes 1025pw 1025sa'
'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', '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' 100000 64 0xB8674F6C0CC9F8CF1F1874534FD5AF01FC1504D76C2BC2AA0A75FE4DD5DFD1DAF60EA7C85F122BCEEB8772659D601231607726998EAC3F6AAB72EFF7BA349F7F 'AW 10b 100000iter 64outBytes 1025pw 1025sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTT', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD' 1 63 0xCBE6088AD4359AF42E603C2A33760EF9D4017A7B2AAD10AF46F992C660A0B461ECB0DC2A79C2570941BEA6A08D15D6887E79F32B132E1C134E9525EEDDD744 'AW Trunc 1a 1iter 63outBytes 19pw 19sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTT', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD' 100000 63 0xACCDCD8798AE5CD85804739015EF2A11E32591B7B7D16F76819B30B0D49D80E1ABEA6C9822B80A1FDFE421E26F5603ECA8A47A64C9A004FB5AF8229F762FF4 'AW Trunc 1b 100000iter 63outBytes 19pw 19sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTl', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2' 1 63 0x8E5074A9513C1F1512C9B1DF1D8BFFA9D8B4EF9105DFC16681222839560FB63264BED6AABF761F180E912A66E0B53D65EC88F6A1519E14804EBA6DC9DF1370 'AW Trunc 2a 1iter 63outBytes 20pw 20sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTl', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2' 100000 63 0x594256B0BD4D6C9F21A87F7BA5772A791A10E6110694F44365CD94670E57F1AECD797EF1D1001938719044C7F018026697845EB9AD97D97DE36AB8786AAB50 'AW Trunc 2b 100000iter 63outBytes 20pw 20sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlR', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2P' 1 63 0xA6AC8C048A7DFD7B838DA88F22C3FAB5BFF15D7CB8D83A62C6721A8FAF6903EAB6152CB7421026E36F2FFEF661EB4384DC276495C71B5CAB72E1C1A38712E5 'AW Trunc 3a 1iter 63outBytes 21pw 21sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlR', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2P' 100000 63 0x94FFC2B1A390B7B8A9E6A44922C330DB2B193ADCF082EECD06057197F35931A9D0EC0EE5C660744B50B61F23119B847E658D179A914807F4B8AB8EB9505AF0 'AW Trunc 3b 100000iter 63outBytes 21pw 21sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE5', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJe' 1 63 0xE2CCC7827F1DD7C33041A98906A8FD7BAE1920A55FCB8F831683F14F1C3979351CB868717E5AB342D9A11ACF0B12D3283931D609B06602DA33F8377D1F1F99 'AW Trunc 4a 1iter 63outBytes 63pw 63sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE5', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJe' 100000 63 0x07447401C85766E4AED583DE2E6BF5A675EABE4F3618281C95616F4FC1FDFE6ECBC1C3982789D4FD941D6584EF534A78BD37AE02555D9455E8F089FDB4DFB6 'AW Trunc 4b 100000iter 63outBytes 63pw 63sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJem' 1 63 0xB029A551117FF36977F283F579DC7065B352266EA243BDD3F920F24D4D141ED8B6E02D96E2D3BDFB76F8D77BA8F4BB548996AD85BB6F11D01A015CE518F9A7 'AW Trunc 5a 1iter 63outBytes 64pw 64sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJem' 100000 63 0x31F5CC83ED0E948C05A15735D818703AAA7BFF3F09F5169CAF5DBA6602A05A4D5CFF5553D42E82E40516D6DC157B8DAEAE61D3FEA456D964CB2F7F9A63BBBD 'AW Trunc 5b 100000iter 63outBytes 64pw 64sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemk' 1 63 0x28B8A9F644D6800612197BB74DF460272E2276DE8CC07AC4897AC24DBC6EB77499FCAF97415244D9A29DA83FC347D09A5DBCFD6BD63FF6E410803DCA8A900A 'AW Trunc 6a 1iter 63outBytes 65pw 65sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemk' 100000 63 0x056BC9072A356B7D4DA60DD66F5968C2CAA375C0220EDA6B47EF8E8D105ED68B44185FE9003FBBA49E2C84240C9E8FD3F5B2F4F6512FD936450253DB37D100 'AW Trunc 6b 100000iter 63outBytes 65pw 65sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi0', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy' 1 63 0x16226C85E4F8D604573008BFE61C10B6947B53990450612DD4A3077F7DEE2116229E68EFD1DF6D73BD3C6D07567790EEA1E8B2AE9A1B046BE593847D9441A1 'AW Trunc 7a 1iter 63outBytes 127pw 127sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi0', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy' 100000 63 0x70CF39F14C4CAF3C81FA288FB46C1DB52D19F72722F7BC84F040676D3371C89C11C50F69BCFBC3ACB0AB9E92E4EF622727A916219554B2FA121BEDDA97FF33 'AW Trunc 7b 100000iter 63outBytes 127pw 127sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6' 1 63 0x880C58C316D3A5B9F05977AB9C60C10ABEEBFAD5CE89CAE62905C1C4F80A0A098D82F95321A6220F8AECCFB45CE6107140899E8D655306AE6396553E285137 'AW Trunc 7a 1iter 63outBytes 128pw 128sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6' 100000 63 0x2668B71B3CA56136B5E87F30E098F6B4371CB5ED95537C7A073DAC30A2D5BE52756ADF5BB2F4320CB11C4E16B24965A9C790DEF0CBC62906920B4F2EB84D1D 'AW Trunc 8b 100000iter 63outBytes 128pw 128sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6P' 1 63 0x93B9BA8283CC17D50EF3B44820828A258A996DE258225D24FB59990A6D0DE82DFB3FE2AC201952100E4CC8F06D883A9131419C0F6F5A6ECB8EC821545F14AD 'AW Trunc 9a 1iter 63outBytes 129pw 129sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6P' 100000 63 0x2575B485AFDF37C260B8F3386D33A60ED929993C9D48AC516EC66B87E06BE54ADE7E7C8CB3417C81603B080A8EEFC56072811129737CED96236B9364E22CE3 'AW Trunc 9b 100000iter 63outBytes 129pw 129sa'
    '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', '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' 100000 63 0xB8674F6C0CC9F8CF1F1874534FD5AF01FC1504D76C2BC2AA0A75FE4DD5DFD1DAF60EA7C85F122BCEEB8772659D601231607726998EAC3F6AAB72EFF7BA349F 'AW Trunc 10b 100000iter 63outBytes 1025pw 1025sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTT', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD' 1 65 0xCBE6088AD4359AF42E603C2A33760EF9D4017A7B2AAD10AF46F992C660A0B461ECB0DC2A79C2570941BEA6A08D15D6887E79F32B132E1C134E9525EEDDD744FA88 'AW Ext 1a 1iter 65outBytes 19pw 19sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTT', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD' 100000 65 0xACCDCD8798AE5CD85804739015EF2A11E32591B7B7D16F76819B30B0D49D80E1ABEA6C9822B80A1FDFE421E26F5603ECA8A47A64C9A004FB5AF8229F762FF41F7C 'AW Ext 1b 100000iter 65outBytes 19pw 19sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTl', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2' 1 65 0x8E5074A9513C1F1512C9B1DF1D8BFFA9D8B4EF9105DFC16681222839560FB63264BED6AABF761F180E912A66E0B53D65EC88F6A1519E14804EBA6DC9DF1370070B 'AW Ext 2a 1iter 65outBytes 20pw 20sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTl', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2' 100000 65 0x594256B0BD4D6C9F21A87F7BA5772A791A10E6110694F44365CD94670E57F1AECD797EF1D1001938719044C7F018026697845EB9AD97D97DE36AB8786AAB5096E7 'AW Ext 2b 100000iter 65outBytes 20pw 20sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlR', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2P' 1 65 0xA6AC8C048A7DFD7B838DA88F22C3FAB5BFF15D7CB8D83A62C6721A8FAF6903EAB6152CB7421026E36F2FFEF661EB4384DC276495C71B5CAB72E1C1A38712E56B93 'AW Ext 3a 1iter 65outBytes 21pw 21sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlR', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2P' 100000 65 0x94FFC2B1A390B7B8A9E6A44922C330DB2B193ADCF082EECD06057197F35931A9D0EC0EE5C660744B50B61F23119B847E658D179A914807F4B8AB8EB9505AF06526 'AW Ext 3b 100000iter 65outBytes 21pw 21sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE5', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJe' 1 65 0xE2CCC7827F1DD7C33041A98906A8FD7BAE1920A55FCB8F831683F14F1C3979351CB868717E5AB342D9A11ACF0B12D3283931D609B06602DA33F8377D1F1F9902DA 'AW Ext 4a 1iter 65outBytes 63pw 63sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE5', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJe' 100000 65 0x07447401C85766E4AED583DE2E6BF5A675EABE4F3618281C95616F4FC1FDFE6ECBC1C3982789D4FD941D6584EF534A78BD37AE02555D9455E8F089FDB4DFB6BB30 'AW Ext 4b 100000iter 65outBytes 63pw 63sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJem' 1 65 0xB029A551117FF36977F283F579DC7065B352266EA243BDD3F920F24D4D141ED8B6E02D96E2D3BDFB76F8D77BA8F4BB548996AD85BB6F11D01A015CE518F9A71780 'AW Ext 5a 1iter 65outBytes 64pw 64sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJem' 100000 65 0x31F5CC83ED0E948C05A15735D818703AAA7BFF3F09F5169CAF5DBA6602A05A4D5CFF5553D42E82E40516D6DC157B8DAEAE61D3FEA456D964CB2F7F9A63BBBDB59F 'AW Ext 5b 100000iter 65outBytes 64pw 64sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemk' 1 65 0x28B8A9F644D6800612197BB74DF460272E2276DE8CC07AC4897AC24DBC6EB77499FCAF97415244D9A29DA83FC347D09A5DBCFD6BD63FF6E410803DCA8A900AB671 'AW Ext 6a 1iter 65outBytes 65pw 65sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemk' 100000 65 0x056BC9072A356B7D4DA60DD66F5968C2CAA375C0220EDA6B47EF8E8D105ED68B44185FE9003FBBA49E2C84240C9E8FD3F5B2F4F6512FD936450253DB37D1002889 'AW Ext 6b 100000iter 65outBytes 65pw 65sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi0', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy' 1 65 0x16226C85E4F8D604573008BFE61C10B6947B53990450612DD4A3077F7DEE2116229E68EFD1DF6D73BD3C6D07567790EEA1E8B2AE9A1B046BE593847D9441A1B766 'AW Ext 7a 1iter 65outBytes 127pw 127sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi0', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy' 100000 65 0x70CF39F14C4CAF3C81FA288FB46C1DB52D19F72722F7BC84F040676D3371C89C11C50F69BCFBC3ACB0AB9E92E4EF622727A916219554B2FA121BEDDA97FF3332EC 'AW Ext 7b 100000iter 65outBytes 127pw 127sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6' 1 65 0x880C58C316D3A5B9F05977AB9C60C10ABEEBFAD5CE89CAE62905C1C4F80A0A098D82F95321A6220F8AECCFB45CE6107140899E8D655306AE6396553E2851376C57 'AW Ext 8a 1iter 65outBytes 128pw 128sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6' 100000 65 0x2668B71B3CA56136B5E87F30E098F6B4371CB5ED95537C7A073DAC30A2D5BE52756ADF5BB2F4320CB11C4E16B24965A9C790DEF0CBC62906920B4F2EB84D1D4A30 'AW Ext 8b 100000iter 65outBytes 128pw 128sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6P' 1 65 0x93B9BA8283CC17D50EF3B44820828A258A996DE258225D24FB59990A6D0DE82DFB3FE2AC201952100E4CC8F06D883A9131419C0F6F5A6ECB8EC821545F14ADF199 'AW Ext 9a 1iter 65outBytes 129pw 129sa'
'passDATAb00AB7YxDTTlRH2dqxDx19GDxDV1zFMz7E6QVqKIzwOtMnlxQLttpE57Un4u12D2YD7oOPpiEvCDYvntXEe4NNPLCnGGeJArbYDEu6xDoCfWH6kbuV6awi04U', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6P' 100000 65 0x2575B485AFDF37C260B8F3386D33A60ED929993C9D48AC516EC66B87E06BE54ADE7E7C8CB3417C81603B080A8EEFC56072811129737CED96236B9364E22CE3A542 'AW Ext 9b 100000iter 65outBytes 129pw 129sa'
'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', 'saltKEYbcTcXHCBxtjD2PnBh44AIQ6XUOCESOhXpEp3HrcGMwbjzQKMSaf63IJemkURWoqHusIeVB8Il91NjiCGQacPUu9qTFaShLbKG0Yj4RCMV56WPj7E14EMpbxy6PlBdILBOkKUB6TGTPJXh1tpdOHTG6KuIvcbQp9qWjaf1uxAKgiTtYRIHhxjJI2viVa6fDZ67QOouOaf2RXQhpsWaTtAVnff6PIFcvJhdPDFGV5nvmZWoCZQodj6yXRDHPw9PyF0iLYm9uFtEunlAAxGB5qqea4X5tZvB1OfLVwymY3a3JPjdxTdvHxCHbqqE0zip61JNqdmeWxGtlRBC6CGoCiHO4XxHCntQBRJDcG0zW7joTdgtTBarsQQhlLXBGMNBSNmmTbDf3hFtawUBCJH18IAiRMwyeQJbJ2bERsY3MVRPuYCf4Au7gN72iGh1lRktSQtEFye7pO46kMXRrEjHQWXInMzzy7X2StXUzHVTFF2VdOoKn0WUqFNvB6PF7qIsOlYKj57bi1Psa34s85WxMSbTkhrd7VHdHZkTVaWdraohXYOePdeEvIwObCGEXkETUzqM5P2yzoBOJSdjpIYaa8zzdLD3yrb1TwCZuJVxsrq0XXY6vErU4QntsW0972XmGNyumFNJiPm4ONKh1RLvS1kddY3nm8276S4TUuZfrRQO8QxZRNuSaZI8JRZp5VojB5DktuMxAQkqoPjQ5Vtb6oXeOyY591CB1MEW1fLTCs0NrL321SaNRMqza1ETogAxpEiYwZ6pIgnMmSqNMRdZnCqA4gMWw1lIVATWK83OCeicNRUNOdfzS7A8vbLcmvKPtpOFvhNzwrrUdkvuKvaYJviQgeR7snGetO9JLCwIlHIj52gMCNU18d32SJl7Xomtl3wIe02SMvq1i1BcaX7lXioqWGmgVqBWU3fsUuGwHi6RUKCCQdEOBfNo2WdpFaCflcgnn0O6jVHCqkv8cQk81AqS00rAmHGCNTwyA6Tq5TXoLlDnC8gAQjDUsZp0z' 1 65 0x384BCD6914407E40C295D1037CF4F990E8F0E720AF43CB706683177016D36D1A14B3A7CF22B5DF8D5D7D44D69610B64251ADE2E7AB54A3813A89935592E391BF91 'AW Ext 10a 1iter 65outBytes 1025pw 1025sa'

'passDATA', 'saltKEYbc' 16777216 7 0xAB96C76400D08B 'AW Spl 1 16777216iter 7outBytes 8pw 9sa'
'passDATAb00AB', 'saltKEYbcTcX' 2097152 481 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pl 2 2097152iter 481outBytes 13pw 12sa'
```

Comment: I get (on my self-created code in [LabVIEW]), the same results as Python/SQL

Comment: Thank you, Tom, and congratulations!  Do we have any idea what particular difference there is between our code and OpenSSL?  I have to suspect it's a <= vs < type of boundary condition issue.

Comment: Thank you, Tom.  At this time, I suspect my oddball OpenSSL results are platform and/or version related.  I need to dive in deeper, but the same C code using OpenSSL libraries on disparate versions and platforms yields different results - one (Windows 7 x64, OpenSSL 1.0.1d x86) get the "Python and SQL" result above, the other (Debian 7 x64, OpenSSL 1.0.1e) gets the "OpenSSL" result above.  I will continue to research over the next days, hopefully with matching OpenSSL 1.0.1f versions.

Comment: At this point, there are no more differences - the old Python/SQL answers match new OpenSSL perfectly: MinGW 4.8.1 and OpenSSL 1.0.1f, as well as Linux with OpenSSL 1.0.1e, all give the same answers as the old Python/SQL answers. There was a platform/version issue with my previous windows setup.  The answer has been updated to match.

Comment: Just another confirmation of the vectors based on the .NET implementation of HMAC SHA-512 (referenced [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341676/how-can-i-hash-passwords-with-salt-and-iterations-using-pbkdf2-hmac-sha-256-or-s/22119356#22119356)). Wondered which would fail before I noticed that you had updated the answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you, @JimmiTh.  I intend to post results for other SHA2 sizes once I have some time and implementations available - are there any suggestions for other boundary condition tests and/or formatting changes?

Comment: Well, the main thing I'm missing would probably be derived key length greater than the PRF output length - I've seen none for SHA-512. Even if it's only of theoretical value as long as we're doing password hashing. For neatness, for SHA-256, I've seen no test vectors with password or salt exceeding PRF output length or derived key length (a la RFC 6070).

Comment: I've got a new set internally with outputlength 65 - exact copy of my current set.  Shameless request to @JimmiTh, Ton Plomp, Fred Federspiel and anyone else with implementations that pass test vectors - I'm just barely starting to try and collect PBKDF2 (and later SCrypt and BCrypt) implementations at [my Github site](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords), and if either of you is willing and legally able to license your code under whatever OSI license, publish it to github or a similar sit, and allow me to fork it/put it in my Github repository/link to it, I would appreciate that very much.

Comment: That's awesome, @JimmiTh!  I guess I need to fork it and figure out how to get .NET to pull in the usual -a algo -p password -s salt -i iterations -o outputBytes parameters, and then let the batch file run through the entire suite of test vectors!

Comment: Added a quick command line tool to the repository which takes those parameters (based on the python implementation, but with some added defaults etc.) - see AwpTest

Answer (score -4):

You're all mad!

The supplied test data doesn't specify the PRF! If you look at the RFC2898 specification here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt you will notice that it shows you how to implement PBKDF2 using a Pseudo Random Function (PRF) but it doesn't tell you what to use as your PRF!

Now to simply say I will use HMACSHA512 as my PRF and therefore my output will be the same as everyone else who uses HMACSHA512 is wrong! If you look at how HMACSHA works, you will note it takes a key. Now the PBKDF2 spec DOES NOT tell you how you should use HMACSHA512. So, for example, I use the password as the key for the HMACSHA512 hashing object I create, and then I do all my hashing using that created object. However someone else might come along and do something different (yet completely legitimate) and say ok, well I will change the HMACSHA key after every hash pass, such that the HMACSHA key is now the value of the last hash.

Also, you can do things like concat Salt + Password instead of Password + Salt and this will also vary your output. The PBKDF2 spec DOES NOT tell you what order you should concatenate your password and salt or when/how you should set the HMACSHA key and this is up to you to implement. So I don't know what standard you are all trying to match your output too.......but essentially all you are doing is making all your frameworks susceptible to attacks by a COMMON RAINBOW TABLE as having output all the same means I can make one table that can be used on everyone achieving the same output....

This be mine https://github.com/Thashiznets/PWDTK.NET in case you wondering what my interest is in this :)

Comment: More completely: [RFC6070](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt) has PBKDF2 HMAC-SHA-1 test vectors, for example.  This question is about PBKDF2 HMAC-SHA-512 test vectors. [RFC2104](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2104) of course specifies order within the HMAC itself, "H(K XOR opad, H(K XOR ipad, text))".  Note that in at least one place RFC2898 does specify concatenation order: on page 8, it says "
                   T_1 = Hash (P || S) ,
                   T_2 = Hash (T_1) ,
                   ...
                   T_c = Hash (T_{c-1}) ,
                   DK = Tc<0..dkLen-1>"

Comment: As far as [RFC2898](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898#section-5.2) not specifying the key for the HMAC, it does: " U_1 = PRF (P, S || INT (i)) , U_2 = PRF (P, U_1) , ...   U_c = PRF (P, U_{c-1}) ." - the first HMAC key is the PBKDF2 salt, and after that it's the prior partial result.

Comment: Hi @Anti-weakpasswords, the concatenation you identify on page 8 is for PBKDF1 NOT PBKDF2.

RFC2898 does not sepcify or even talk about a HMAC key. It talks about a PRF, the PRF DOES NOT even have to be HMAC!!! You can use SHA-1 for example! The person implementing the PRF decides to use HMAC and controls the HMAC key. Why can't I use the Password as HMAC key instead of Salt? Where does it say I can't do that?

Comment: Re @thashiznets, [https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) has that construction on page 10, which is part of the PBKDF2 specification that starts at the bottom of page 9, i.e. section 5.2 PBKDF2.

Comment: @thashiznets, Test vectors and elimination of ambiguity from the algorithm are both needed to verify that any code correctly implements the well-tested algorithms.  Once that's done, the random salt used in a real implementation defeats a common rainbow attack.  Obscurity in the concatenation order doesn't put much burden on an attacker, but a mistake in implementation could make his job much easier.

Comment: @FredFederspiel well it is being used in the bitcoin BIP39 c# implementation and the output matches what is expected by them and all I had to do was shift the salt and the password or something but it makes no difference to security if you know how HMACSHA works so it's a non issue.

Comment: This code works, is solid, and if I change it so that it matches everyone else all it does is break the password of all the users of the >2000 projects that have downloaded it on nuget. Maybe I could set a standards flag in there and just keep it set to false and if anyone wants to run it to be the same as everyone else they can set standards mode to true. I for one enjoy having that extra bit of security that comes by not working with ANY pbkdf2 rainbow tables.

Comment: So if the govt for example has a super computer there churning away a rainbow table for 5000 iteration pbkfdf2 well guess what my non matching one won't be susceptible to their table :)