# Seed from BIP39 Mnemonic not matching Test Vectors

Tags: java, bitcoin, pbkdf2

I'm writing a Java implementation of Bitcoin's BIP39. So far, my code is able to produce a randomly generated mnemonic phrase correctly. However, when converting the 12 word Mnemonic Phrase into a 512-bit seed, the resulting value does not match with results from [Ian Coleman's BIP39 Tool](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/).

To start, a SecureRandom object generates a random 512-bit Entropy value (ENT). The ENT value is hashed using SHA256 to compute the checksum value (CS), which is the first 4 bits of the hash. The checksum is concatenated to end of ENT to give ENT_CS. ENT_CS is split into sections of 11 bits each, and the corresponding integer value of the 11 bits is used as the index number to obtain a word from the Word List. This generates my 12 word Mnemonic Phrase. So far, all steps up to this point match the expected results from aforementioned BIP39 Tool.

To create the Seed, I am using PBKDF2 with HmacSHA512, setting the iterations to 2048, and the key-size to 512 bits (64 bytes). I have tested my implementation of PBKDF2 against these [Test Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593184/pbkdf2-hmac-sha-512-test-vectors), Google's "crypto" package implementation, and NovaCrypto's Java BIP39 implementation. The mnemonic words, excluding separators, is used as input along with a salt of `"mnemonic"+password` as per the [Bitcoin Core BIP39 Specifications](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki).

### PBKDF2 Function

```java
  public static byte[] PBKDF2(String mnemonic, String salt) {
    try {
      byte[] fixedSalt = ("mnemonic"+salt).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(mnemonic.toCharArray(), fixedSalt, 2048, 512);
      SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
      return f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }
```

### Generate Mnemonic Function

```java
public static String[] generateMnemonic() {
  // Generate 128-bit Random Number for Entropy
  byte[] ENT = getEntropy();

  // Hash the Entropy value
  byte[] HASH = SHA256(ENT);

  // Copy first 4 bits of Hash as Checksum
  boolean[] CS = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytesToBits(HASH), 0, 4);

  // Add Checksum to the end of Entropy bits
  boolean[] ENT_CS = Arrays.copyOf(bytesToBits(ENT), bytesToBits(ENT).length + CS.length);
  System.arraycopy(CS, 0, ENT_CS, bytesToBits(ENT).length, CS.length);

  // Split ENT_CS into groups of 11 bits and creates String array for
  // mnemonicWords
  String[] mnemonicWords = new String[12];
  for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    boolean[] numBits = Arrays.copyOfRange(ENT_CS, i * 11, i * 11 + 11);
    mnemonicWords[i] = wordList.get(bitsToInt(numBits));
  }
  return mnemonicWords;
}
```

### Helper Functions

```java
// Returns randomly generated, 16-byte number
  public static byte[] getEntropy() {
    byte[] ent = new byte[16];
    sr.nextBytes(ent);
    return ent;
  }

// Returns bit representation of byte array
  public static boolean[] bytesToBits(byte[] data) {
    boolean[] bits = new boolean[data.length * 8];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i)
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        bits[(i * 8) + j] = (data[i] & (1 << (7 - j))) != 0;
    return bits;
  }

// Returns hex string from byte array
  private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
  public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
      int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
      hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
      hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
  }

// Returns SHA256 hash of input data
  public static byte[] SHA256(byte[] data) {
    try {
      MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
      return digest.digest(data);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }

// Returns int value of a bit array
  public static int bitsToInt(boolean[] bits) {
    int n = 0, l = bits.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
      n = (n << 1) + (bits[i] ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return n;
  }
```

### Usage

```java
// Generate Mnemonic Words, Mnemonic Phrase, and Seed
    String[] mnemonicWords = generateMnemonic();
    String mnemonicPhrase = "";
    for (String word : mnemonicWords)
      mnemonicPhrase += word;
    byte[] seed = PBKDF2(mnemonicPhrase, "");
    System.out.println("Seed: " + bytesToHex(seed));
```

### Example Results

```
    My Program Trial
Entropy (hex): 3CCB62D9AF76F1E8DB113E66B2D84656
Checksum bits: 1100
Raw Binary: 00111100110 01011011000 10110110011 01011110111 01101111000 11110100011 01101100010 00100111110 01100110101 10010110110 00010001100 1010110
Mnemonic: devote force reopen galaxy humor virtual hobby chief grit nothing bag pulse
Seed: 013FFA714C57AA26C59DC215880D9C2398A8B38D10D7E41A882CF98C35976F0BF26BCC08B0B196945DE8778C7FD561FB0F20A8B9BAD46B12196C963A85E3B40E

    Expected Results (Derived from same Entropy)
Entropy (hex): 3CCB62D9AF76F1E8DB113E66B2D84656
Checksum bits: 1100
Raw Binary: 00111100110 01011011000 10110110011 01011110111 01101111000 11110100011 01101100010 00100111110 01100110101 10010110110 00010001100 1010110
Mnemonic: devote force reopen galaxy humor virtual hobby chief grit nothing bag pulse
Seed: 0c3c5f9ae724a2a3ed70aeb24919c10506e4962223a5375f70164be8b897d615ec9bf9f3e64a889cff03318cc5d0b3c8378ba0264d198e307c609632016ddd01
```

Comment: Can you tell us Q?

Comment: @MS90 The Q of what? I'm not attempting to create keypairs from the seed yet, just trying to generate a correct Seed from a mnemonic phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was able to answer my own question.
In my program, I was concatenating the seed words without spaces using

```java
String mnemonicPhrase = "";
for (String word : mnemonicWords)
  mnemonicPhrase += word;
```

But this is not the correct format, as the spaces are to be included. Changing this code block to add spaces:

```java
String mnemonicPhrase = "";
for(int i=0; i<mnemonicWords.length; i++) {
    mnemonicPhrase += mnemonicWords[i];
    if(i < mnemonicWords.length-1) mnemonicPhrase += " ";
}
```

yields expected Test Vector results published [here](https://github.com/trezor/python-mnemonic/blob/master/vectors.json) using a password of "TREZOR".

Answer (score -1):

String mnemonicPhrase = "";
for (String word : mnemonicWords)
mnemonicPhrase += word bc1qsrgkdlk8ruk7uyer3jkv502ykww243yu367ay9

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).