# PBKDF2 Lua Implementation Issue

Tags: lua, sha256, hmac, pbkdf2

I am trying to write a PBKDF2 implementation in pure lua. I am writing it because I want to use it in a sandboxed lua environment that does not allow outside libraries. I had a look at the standard document from the IETF and had at it. Below is the code I have come up with:

```
do
    package.preload["pbkdf2"] = function()

        local hmac = require 'hmac'
        local len = string.len
        local gsub = string.gsub
        local format = string.format
        local byte = string.byte
        local char = string.char
        local concat = table.concat
        local ceil = math.ceil

        local function toBytes(str)
            local tmp = {}
            for i = 1, len(str) do
                tmp[i] = byte(str, i)
            end
            return tmp
        end

        local function toString(bArray)
            local tmp = {}
            for i = 1, #bArray do
                tmp[i] = char(bArray[i])
            end
            tmp = concat(tmp)
            return tmp
        end

        -- transform a string of bytes in a string of hexadecimal digits
        local function asHex(s)
            local h = gsub(s, ".", function(c)
                return format("%02x", byte(c))
            end)
            return h
        end

        local num2string = function(l, n)
            local s = {}
            for i = 1, n do
                local idx = (n + 1) - i
                s[idx] = char(l & 255)
                l = l >> 8
            end
            s = concat(s)
            return s
        end

        local buildBlock = function(hFun, password, salt, c, int)
            local tmp
            local tmp2

            for i = 1, c do
                if i == 1 then
                    print(int)
                    print(salt .. int)
                    -- PRF(password, salt || INT_32_BE(i)
                    -- return result of hash as a byte string
                    tmp = hmac.hash(hFun, password, salt .. num2string(int, 4), true)
                else
                    -- returns result of hash as byte string
                    tmp2 = hmac.hash(hFun, password, tmp, true)
                    -- transform to byte arrays
                    tmp2 = toBytes(tmp2)
                    tmp = toBytes(tmp)
                    assert(#tmp == #tmp2)
                    -- apply XOR over bytes in both arrays
                    -- save results to final array
                    for j = 1, #tmp do
                        -- perform XOR operation on both elements in the respective arrays
                        tmp[j] = tmp[j] ~ tmp2[j]
                    end
                    -- transform back into byte string to pass to next hash
                    tmp = toString(tmp)
                end
            end
            return tmp
        end

        local truncate = function(str, pos)
            return string.sub(str, 1, pos)
        end

        local deriveKey = function(hFun, message, salt, c, dLen)
            local hLen = hFun.outputSize

            -- the derived key cannot be larger than (2^32 * hLen)
            if dLen > (2^32) * hLen then error("The derived key cannot be larger than 2^32 times the output size of the hash function.") end

            -- the block size is the desired key length divided by the output size of the underlying hash function, rounded up
            local blockSize = ceil(dLen/hLen)

            -- to store our blocks
            local final = {}

            for i = 1, blockSize do
                -- lets make our blocks in here
                final[i] = buildBlock(hFun, message, salt, c, i)
            end

            local result
            if #final == 1 then
                result = final[1] -- we only have one block
            else
                result = concat(final) -- turns final into a bytestring to be outputted
            end
            --if #result > dLen then truncate(final, dLen) end
            assert(#result == dLen)
            return asHex(result) -- outputs as a hex value
        end
        return {deriveKey = deriveKey}
    end
end
```

This code is not getting the correct answers. Testing this code with test vectors provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5136918/9821157), assuming that the underlying PRF is HMAC-SHA256, the output is below:

```
key: "password"
salt: "salt"
c: 1
dkLen: 32

Got: 13463842ec330934dc124494b40d8baade465b72f3fcadad741f2d0e052fd2f5
Expected: 120fb6cffcf8b32c43e7225256c4f837a86548c92ccc35480805987cb70be17b

key: "password"
salt: "salt"
c: 2
dkLen: 32

Got: 8b82aed26f503effdbc6c14bc7f0338b2b90e387f14ac1f91f9ad74e618f9558
Expected: AE4D0C95AF6B46D32D0ADFF928F06DD02A303F8EF3C251DFD6E2D85A95474C43
```

I believe it may have something to do with the string to byte encoding, but I cannot pinpoint what exactly is causing the issue. When I was testing my HMAC code, I had to rely on online generators because I couldn't find vectors for HMAC-SHA224 and HMAC-SHA256. Some calculators would give me completely different output values for the same key, message combination. That could be because of how they are processing the inputs, but I am not sure. I would appreciate it if someone more experienced could help me out with this.

EDIT: This problem is solved. Seems that all that was needed was to pass *int* as a binary string of length 4. I updated the code with the fixes.

EDIT 2: I read the standard again to realize the solution was in my face the entire time (standard says to encode i as a 32-bit big endian integer).

Comment: This line is strange `if #result > dLen then truncate(final, dLen) end`

Comment: I meant to remove that line @EgorSkriptunoff It and the truncate method itself make no difference in the issues above.

Comment: The expression `salt .. int` looks suspicious: you are converting integer into its decimal representation and concatenate this string with "salt".

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff printing the value of `salt .. int` gives "salt1" as a result for int = 1, and actually having `"salt1.0" passed in would give a different answer for the PBKDF, but one that is still incorrect. Using math.floor and tostring on int also do not change things. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: You should calculate `salt..num2string(int, 4)` instead (convert `int` to big-endian binary string of length 4)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff that worked! thank you for your help. I will update the post with the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to convert *int* to a binary string of length 4. Thanks to @EgorSkriptunoff for his insight.